# Exception when calling closeWithCompletionHandler: on a UIDocument more than once

Tags: cocoa-touch, uidocument

Can a single instance of a UIDocument not be opened and closed multiple times? It seems that I can open, close, and re-open a document, but as soon as I try to call closeWithCompletionHandler: on it a second time I get an exception:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'closeWithCompletionHandler called while document is already closing'`

Prior to the call the documentState is Normal.

Hopefully I'm just overlooking something obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-opening a closed document with openWithCompletionHandler, create a fresh UIDocument subclass instance and initialize it first with initWithFileURL and then open it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Wish the docs made this a little more clear. I guess I should file a bug.